# Pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a python function in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am using **Flask**. I want to call a function using **globals**.

I make an API call using parameters passed as a dictionary:

```
my_parameters = {
    "function" : "add_numbers",
    "number_1" : 100,
    "number_2" : 200
}
```

I can **call the function** in Flask as follows:

```
@app.route("/call_my_function/", methods=["GET"])
    def call_my_function():
        res = globals()[request.args.get('function')](100, 200)
        return(res)
```

...which works fine, but as you can see I am harcoding the 100 and 200 arguments. I want these arguments to be **passed** from the `my_parameters` dictionary. I tried this:

```
@app.route("/call_my_function/", methods=["GET"])
    def call_my_function():
        res = globals()[request.args.get('function')](list(args.values())[1:])
        return(res)
```

But the arguments are not accepted in globals. It says:

```
TypeError: add_numbers() missing 1 required positional argument
```

Comment: Using tuple *unpack* should do the magic: `globals()[request.args.get('function')](*args.values())`

Comment: This doesn't remove the "function" argument from the parameter object. Is there a way to remove the first element from the *args.values()? In other words, this gives the "takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" error. Problem being tuples are immutable.

Comment: First get values as list `values = list(args.values())[1:]` then pass as tuple `globals()[request.args.get('function')](*tuple(values))`

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)